# How to hide Refresh Control under UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using:

- **XCode 9**
- **Swift 4**

My `CollectionView` code is pretty simple:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
   refreshControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

   collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
   collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}

@objc private func onRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
   refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

After I pull `collectionView` and the `refreshControl` will appear, if I scroll `collectionView` back to the top, then the `refreshControl` is drawn over the cells:

[image]

I found the solution for this case:

`refreshControl.layer.zPosition = -1`

But now `Refresh Controll` lies behind cells and viewed through spaces between them:
[image]

The result I want to get is very simple and logical. I assume that it works with the `TableView` since the cells in it have background filling. Why did not Apple initially support this approach with a `CollectionView`:

[image]

Comment: You should make sure you complete the view lifecycle by calling super.viewDidLoad() at the beginning of the override.

Comment: @SwiftRabbit thanks for the answer, but I gave a shortened version of the code. Now I edited the answer according to your hint

Comment: You are not calling the selector correctly. Currently you are using #selector(onRefresh). No parameter is passed here. I wonder how your onRefresh is getting called OR at first place, your code is getting compiled.

Comment: @Nitish do not worry, the code works!

Comment: Please help me understand, how the code works. Because to my understanding it won't even compile.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried adding the refreshControl to the index: 0, addSubView, addSubView and send to back.  Also for my project, the refresh control is a little off center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to add the following after the instance of refreshcontrol is set:

```
        refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Hope this helps~

Comment: Amazing! But it is enough to specify only the background color:
`refreshControl.backgroundColor = .white`
Thank you very much!